# why whole xpath syntax is placed in square brackets

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I am executing a selenium script
there is a xpath as
//span[contains(text(),'Country')]//following::span[text()='Node']/../..//select

while executing it is failed by saying
[Chromedriver:xpath //span[contains(text(),'Country')]//following::span[text()='Node']/../..//select] Could not be found

Why this extra square bracket[] is added while execution.
If I get the print statement for same syntax it shows without square bracket[]

Can somebody please help me
why this is adding and how to resolve this

Comment: Can you include the code you are running to see this exception? What language are you using, even?

Comment: Which is the extra bracket, the one after `select`? That seems like just part of the error message

Comment: Thanks Peck. Language used is Java and The output is surrounded in square brackets like here before chromedriver and a t the end after select. Here you can see it, [Chromedriver:xpath //span[contains(text(),'Country')]//following::span[text()='Node']/../..//select]

Comment: OK, and what is the HTML of the page you are testing?